# What is the behaviour of kafka when a commit is made without reading the message?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have code that looks like.

```
def message_reader(consumer):
    consumed_message = consumer.consume_batch()
    if consumed_message:
        #do something

def run_reader():
    process_consumer = get_consumer() #gets a SimpleConsumer()
    message_reader(process_consumer)
    process_consumer.commit()
    process_consumer.close()
```

so, my question is , Suppose there is no message in the topic and no messages are consumed - does the commit() increase the offset?

And also, does the producer check for the latest offset before producing a message ?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on the python client, but the java one would just re-commit the same position if it hasn't actually consumed anything between commit calls.

I'm certain, however, that all clients do the same (commit the same position) as doing otherwise would cause you to skip records. There are also entire Kafka monitoring systems that have been written to rely on this behavior - for example [burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow).

Comment: Yep .. Seems like this is the default behavior .  But for some reason , my consumers are not picking any message from the topic for some time and then they do. So i suspected that the offset was being wrongly incremented.. Seems like there's some other issue I'm not able to find out.